# $rootScope:infdig error in AngularJS when using ng-disabled to validate a collection of elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-scope, infinite-loop

I've got an issue with an AngularJS app I'm writing, and I've created a very simplified version of it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/55JlCxVV1SSKfcQgbICb?p=preview

My issue is that, when using ng-disabled to cause the form to validate, and subsequently display validation errors, and, obviously, enable/disable the Save button.

```
    <button ng-disabled="!validate()" ng-click="save()">Save</button>

    $scope.validate = function() {
      var valid = true;
      if (!$scope.foo || $scope.foo.length < 5) {
        valid = false;
        messageService.addMessage('ERROR', 'foo', 'foo must be at least 5 characters', 0);
      } else {
        messageService.deleteMessage('ERROR', 'foo');
      }
      if (!$scope.bar || $scope.bar < 10) {
        valid = false;
        messageService.addMessage('ERROR', 'bar', 'bar must be at least 10', 0);
      } else {
        messageService.deleteMessage('ERROR', 'bar');
      }
      if (!$scope.wotsit || $scope.wotsit.length > 15) {
        valid = false;
        messageService.addMessage('ERROR', 'wotsit', 'wotsit must be less than 15 characters', 0);
      } else {
        messageService.deleteMessage('ERROR', 'wotsit');
      }
      return valid;
    };
```

I also have another small question (possibly outside the scope of this question, but I'll ask it anyway!) - in thingController.save() - you'll see I clear all of the currently visible messages (catch all - if this particular form has validated, there will be no messages - but in the real app it makes sense), and then add one confirming the save action, but this seems to be added to the messages object, then instantly removed? Confusing, but most likely my error - if anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be awesome.

```
$scope.save = function() {
    if ($scope.validate()) {
        messageService.clearAllMessages();
        messageService.addMessage('SUCCESS', 'save', 'Saved some stuff, promise', 0);
    }
};
```

As a bit of an aside, I realise that all of the validation I'm currently applying could be achieved using out of the box AngularJS validation directives, but the validation in the real app can't be, so the solution would need to continue to use this method of validating.

Many thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
$scope.$watch('messages', function() {
    console.log(messageService);
    $scope.messages = messageService.messages;
}, true);
```

If you click the error link from AngularJS it will explain what the problem is with a very similar example. The main idea is that you are watching for $scope.messages and inside you are changing $scope.messages value which will trigger the $watch again ... and so on ... for an infinite number of times. To prevent that Angular has a build in fail system to stop the infinite loop.

Comment: Ah, thanks, so how would I get around this, so that the **messagesController** is always aware when the **messageService.messages** object changes?

Comment: You can send an event from where you are updating it. I noticed you have a $broadcast event somewhere but you where never listening to it. So just to a $scope($rootScope).$on in the controller to listen for an event.

Comment: Sorry, but I've still got an infdig in this?

$rootScope.$on('messages', function(){
      $scope.messages = messageService.messages;
    });

Comment: The infinite digest loop error appears because the $scope.messages gets update to many times and it's used in an ng-repeat, something that's pointed in the error page. From what I've seen, the addMessage method is being called to many times (more than it should) and it's broadcasting the event to many times. I wasn't able to find the problem but as a side thing you don't need to use the service in your messagesController as you can send the message object through the $broadcast event.